# Tabulator 5.0 - parsing datetime luxon - datetime ISO 8601

Tags: javascript, tabulator, luxon

I currently try to parse datetime in tabulator js library. My datetime string is "2021-09-11T00:00:00.000Z".

On the last release, they change the datetime library to luxon. I didn't success to find the good format for that kind of date. In the documentation, it seems that they kept the last datetime library moment.js.
I read the luxon documentation but i didn't succeed.

I tried :

> {title:"Début Campagne", field:"start_date" ,formatter:"datetime",
> formatterParams:{
> inputFormat:"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss:SSSZ",
> outputFormat:"dd/MM/yyyy"}}

The way tabulator use luxon, i can't use the function Datetime.FromIso than can parse ISO 8601 so i have to found the correct format.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 4):

As of Tabulator v5.1 there is now built in iso support for formatters

```js
{title:"Example", field:"example", formatter:"datetime", formatterParams:{
    inputFormat:"iso",
}}
```

And sorters:

```js
{title:"Example", field:"example", sorter:"datetime", sorterParams:{
    format:"iso",
}}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you see [datetime](https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/blob/41e79e1eacbb285783f561899e5e8836d2e0d75d/src/js/modules/Format/defaults/formatters/datetime.js#L9) , there you can see that you will not able to use ISO date here.. In your case you are using ISO data format which needs to be format using `fromISO` and then you can format it.

It might help you [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-70356141-zofo7?file=/src/index.js)

Comment: Thank you very much, it's a good walkaround. I finally modifed the tabulator library to handle iso format. I also asked tabulator team to implement this functionality.